# Understanding the math used to generate a point cloud from a depth image

Tags: computer-vision

In reviewing various algorithms for converting a depth image to a point cloud where the camera
has extrinsic parameters

- $c_x, c_y$ the center point of a camera
- $f_x = f*m_x$, where $f$ is the focal length of the camera
- $f_y = f*m_y$

and $m_x,m_y$ are scale factors relating the width\height of the sensor to the number of pixels

i.e. $m_x $ = (width_of_sensor)/(num_pixels_in_horiztonal_direction) (not 100% sure about this) and similarly for $m_y$.

Then a formula for each $[u,v]$ in pixel space (with its corresponding $z=z_{u,v}$) to be converted to a 3d vector is

$x = ((u - c_x)/f_x) * z$

$y = ((v - c_x)/f_x) * z$

$z = z$

I'm trying to understand the geometry of these equations if they are correct. Any insights appreciated.

Edit: I'm not sure what $c_x, c_y$ are. Are they roughly half the number of pixels in the image sensor? So for example for a depth image of resolution $600 \times 600$, $c_x, c_y = 300$, or rather are they a point in world space, in which case what is the relationship between $u,v$ and $c_x, c_y$ ?